# How do I install anacron?

Tags: linux, cron, suse

I'm running Suse in a VM (SLES12). I wanted to automate a script and was using crontab at first, but it doesn't work when my system is off. So I looked into anacron, however I can't seem to find a solution anywhere as to how to install it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone who wants to know. I had to manually

```
wget
```

the rpm from http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/opensuse/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/suse/i586/ for cronie-anacron to install it on my machine so that

```
sudo zypper install cronie-anacron
```

works.

Comment: To automate using `zypper`, you must have the repository (repos) containing the desired package configured. Check the repos you have configured with `zypper lr`. To add a repository use `zypper ar URL alias`. E.g. `zypper ar http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/opensuse/distribution/12.1/repo/oss oss`